# Web2Py can't iterate over list in a view using jQuery

Tags: jquery, web2py

So I am not exactly sure what I should be looking up to solve this problem. I just know it's a problem. So I have a view that has a list returned to it of episode names. In the view I have a button that with a jQuery call, I want to cycle through episodes each time the button is pressed. I create an iterator but the problem is, if I increase the iterator in the jQuery function, its scope keeps it from keeping it's value the next time the button is pressed, meaning it can only go up by one. The code kind of looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
{{iter = 0}}
$('#nextButton').click(function(){
    {{iter = iter + 1}}
    $('.firstEp').children().remove()
    $('.firstEp').append('<p>epList[iter]</p>')
});
```

So iter can increase the one time you press the button but not after. What can I use to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had a list in python that I wanted to iterate over in my jQuery function. In order to do that I had to turn it into a javascript array first. I could do this with

`jsArray{{=XML(response.json(pyList))}}`

where pyList is your python list and jsArray is the javascript array. You can iterate over do whatever you please to jsArray in your jQuery event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
{{iter = 0}} <-- WEB2PY TEMPLATE CODE
$('#nextButton').click(function(){
    {{iter = iter + 1}} <-- WEB2PY TEMPLATE CODE
    $('.firstEp').children().remove()
    $('.firstEp').append('<p>epList[iter]</p>')
});
```

Assuming the above is in a web2py template, the two lines marked above are web2py template code, which is Python that gets executed on the server before returning the HTML page to the browser. In this case, because each line does not start with `=`, nothing will be written to the page, so the Javascript that gets written will simply have blank lines in those places. Instead, you need to write all of this in Javascript.

Comment: How can I iterate over a list in python with a javascript variable. The list I am getting comes from my controller, there is not preventing that. I just want to iterate over it on each button click.

Comment: Sorry, it's not at all clear what you are trying to do. If you need clicks in the browser to make changes on the server, then you probably need to use Ajax. I suggest you ask for help on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/web2py) and show more of your code (i.e., the controller code).

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I needed to turn my python list into a javascript array using  {{=XML(response.json(pythonList))}}. That let me iterate one element at a time. Thank you for the help